# Gingerbread not loading manifest file

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am creating a app from a existing source (Gingerbread download softkeyboard) when it loads into eclipse it only loads empty folders, there isnt even a Java file other then the gen java file.

It says the manifest is missing but when I look into the Gingerbread folder outside of eclipse the manifest file is there along with a slew of other files that eclipse did not load. What could be the issue?

Also when I try to import (I've tried by root and archive) it gives an error of no projects found.

Comment: Where did you try to download from?  

Also, does the folder have the standard .classpath, .project, project.properties, proguard.cfg files (that's what are in most of my project files)

Comment: I downloaded from github and no it doesnt have the standard files it has proguard.flag titled Flagsfile type, MK file, GITIGNORE file and some other files...these are files and extensions I am not familiar with..

Comment: I went back to the github site and it said this for the keyboard There aren't any downloads yet. But don't worry! You can download the source code as a zip or tarball above...so I re-downloaded the zip file and the same thing happened again..not loading files

Comment: Ok I believe that the gingerbread file was not created with eclipse therefore eclipse is not recognizing it as a project due to the file not containing classpath, project properties file etc.. I am going to see if I can edit the files to add eclipse extensions..maybe that will work..

Comment: Ok so I found the problem its Android NDK code!!!

Comment: I had to adjust the API in preferences to suit the NDK package however it still doesnt load certain files therefore I had to manually copy the files into the folder inside of my workspace I was able to access some of the files but not the mk files it only opened in notepad so Im still working on this...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is going into the folder that you imported your project from. Copy the files from it, including the Android Manifest file. Then go into the folder eclipse created in your workspace and paste the contents into it. This will overwrite the default folders that eclipse created. Go back into eclipse and f5 and you should see your files how up.